# How to get the content in the table within a CVirtualGridCtrl control of a window through pywinauto

Tags: ui-automation, pywinauto

I am trying to get the content of a table within a GridCtrl control as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I have found through spy++ that the control containing the table is CVirtualGridCtrl.

[image]

But how can I get the content of the table?

```
app = pywinauto.Application().Connect(path = "xiadan.exe")
control = app[u'网上股票交易系统5.0'].CVirtualGridCtrl
control.PrintControlIdentifiers()
```

If I run the above code, I will get the following output:

[image]

Having searched and test for a long time, I still have no clue. 
Could someone kindly give me a hint? Thanks a lot.

---

Edit: 
Really appreciate your quick response @vasily-ryabov. I have tried as you suggested, unfortunately there is no recognizable control to get the numbers I want.

[image]

Does this mean that it is then impossible to get the content of the cells?
I have also tried right clicked on the control, but there is no interested short-cut operation.

Comment: Did you try to use `Inspect.exe` instead of Spy++? as provided [here](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Comment: I'm afraid grids are not supported by Win32 API backend (which is default one). But UI Automation API backend has more chances to recognize the cells.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer @vasily-ryabov.  I have tried as you said in the question.

Comment: Looks like UIA backend won't help. If it's standard MFC GridCtrl class, it needs to add special window message handlers on app side + implementing custom GridWrapper in pywinauto (or as a monkey patch). I made it at my previous job, but it was kept privately. So I can advice you on this way, but can't do all the job. Sorry. It would be first public example to implement custom control support.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use clipboard to get grid data.

```
control.type_keys('^A^C')
data = pywinauto.clipboard.GetData()
```